# Lazy Instantiation in the View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a button that triggers a random sound from an array in a class. I have lazy instantiation in my view controller that is triggered by an IBAction, but I feel this is incorrect because of two reasons:

**1)** I usually see people doing L.I. in ***getters and setters***.

*When I try to do the L.I. in the getter/setter, my program crashes and I don't know why.*

**2)** I am performing this lazy instantiation *inside of the view controller IBAction*.

**Is this a correct way to do Lazy Instantiation?**

here is the code that does not crash:

```
- (IBAction)myClass:(UIButton *)sender
{

    if (!self.myClass){
        self.myClass = [[myClass alloc] init];
        [self.myClass setUpMyClass]; // this method just loads sounds and some text
    }


    [self.myClass playSound];
    self.myClassLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [self.myClass someText]];

}
```

here is the code that crashes:

```
- (myClass *)myClass
{

    if (!self.myClass){
        self.myClass = [[myClass alloc] init];
        [self.myClass setUpMyClass]; // this method just loads sounds and some text
    }

    return self.myClass;
}

- (IBAction)myClass:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.myClass playSound];
    self.myClassLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [self.myClass someText]];

}
```

The out put in the debugger doesn't say much but there is a green arrow next to the line that says

```
-(myClass *) myClass {
```

and it says

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address =0xbf7ffffc)
```

for user named aqua, the method setUpMyMethod looks like this:

```
-(void) setUpEscha{
    self.eschaDialogue = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                       [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound1" ofType:@"mp3"],
                       [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound1" ofType:@"mp3"],
                       ...
                       nil];

self.eschaLines = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    @"String1",
                    @"String2",
                    @"...",
                    nil];
```

}

Comment: Your code looks fine in general. But if you want any real help you need to update your question with exact details about the crash. Include the error and a stack trace.

Comment: Can you provide the information from the debugger, or show the code for `setUpMyClass`?

Comment: Side note: The last line should be: `self.myClassLabel.text = [self.myClass someText];`. This assumes that `[self.myClass someText]` returns an `NSString`.

Comment: @aqua the method "setUpMyClass" is not the problem, but if you must know all it does is set up two arrays, one with sounds and one with strings. Look above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your getter is calling itself recursively. Don't access `self.myClass` within the `myClass` getter. Change your code to:

```
- (myClass *)myClass
{
    if (!_myClass){
        _myClass = [[myClass alloc] init];
        [_myClass setUpMyClass]; // this method just loads sounds and some text
    }
    return _myClass;
}
```

This is assuming your iVar for `myClass` is `_myClass`. If not, change `_myClass` to whatever the iVar is.

For future questions along the lines of "why does XXX crash" it's helpful if you include the debugger log and stack trace from the crash.

Comment: how to i see the stack trace?

Comment: it doesn't really matter whether the property is public or private. as long as you are referencing the iVar correctly this should fix the problem. If you're still having difficulties you'll need to post the code where you declare the iVar, the property, and any `@synthesize` statements relating to it.

Comment: i fixed it, i was changing it to self._myClass when it should have been _myClass. It is working now.. Thanks!

Comment: ok, great. no need for me to add more to the answer then. I'm sure there are some good Q&A on SO wrt how to see a stack trace in xcode... :) happy coding.